Is it worth using OptIn in a commercial app?
Now i am coding my android app which i am going to release on Google Play. I use compose for ui. TopAppBar element requires using OptIn annotation since it's marked with ExperimentalMaterial3Api which states that This material API is experimental and is likely to change or to be removed in the future.
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@Composable
fun TopAppBar(
    title: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navigationIcon: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    actions: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit = {},
    windowInsets: WindowInsets = TopAppBarDefaults.windowInsets,
    colors: TopAppBarColors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(),
    scrollBehavior: TopAppBarScrollBehavior? = null
) {

@RequiresOptIn(
    "This material API is experimental and is likely to change or to be removed in" +
        " the future."
)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class ExperimentalMaterial3Api

So is it worth using OptIn in a commercial app ? Or it's better to use some alternatives to avoid potential issues ?

All it means is the API is not final yet. There is no harm in using it but just know it could change in future versions until it is finalized. There are a lot of material components that you need to opt in to with compose

It's written there that be removed in the future. So there is a chance that after updating version of this library, there will not TopAppBar function and i will have to do a lot of work to make my app work again. That's why i am worrying. @tyczj

Is it possible its removed? Sure I guess but is it likely, no. I have never seen an API get removed from anything in android, just deprecated

RequiresOptIn means the API is delicate and can likely change. However, any change in the underlying API won't affect your live users. They are affected only when you publish an update to them. One thing to consider though is that the use of RequiresOptIn is contagious meaning all of its usages will require the opt-in. So, if you are going to use it sparsely and there isn't a good alternative, I would say go with it because that way less of your code will be affected and there will be less tech debt in future when you eventually are to replace it with some stable API. I would say avoid it if possible, but do not stay blocked because of this. GTM is more important than minor technical consideration especially for indie devs.

A simple example of how this effected my app would be the BasicTextFeild2 composable which I am using now, but it is being removed or to be exact merged with BasicTextField in the coming updates, so I have to change all composables which use BasicTextField2, here changing it is not just renaming as some aspects of BasicTextField2 are now discontinued for example textState as flow is now no longer an option so I have to change it's working to.
In a similar way if you opt-In for any experimental API be prepared to change your code if that particular feature is changed and changes here might be drastic.
